# Veiw is not refreshing after refeshing the scope variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Check the plunker:** [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WH3rFXenP4Mj3mL0Xfwd?p=preview)

**Controller:**

```
appRoot.controller('IndexCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.ToggleSwithchTrigglerCount = 0;
  $scope.ToggleSwitchWidgetConfig=myService.ToggleSwitchWidgetConfig;
  $scope.SwitchToggled = function() {
    $scope.ToggleSwithchTrigglerCount++;

    //since single click of the toggle switch triggers the two click events, 
    //In first call the check box state will be unchecked
    //In second call it will have the changed state
    //I am executing following code on second event since at that time check box will be in final state 
    if ($scope.ToggleSwithchTrigglerCount == 2) {

      $scope.CurrentSwithIndex = this.config.Index;

      //call the method from service
      myService.SwitchToggled($scope);

      //now get the updated config object in scope variable so that view can be updated
      $scope.ToggleSwitchWidgetConfig = myService.ToggleSwitchWidgetConfig;

    }

  };
});
```

**Service:**

```
appRoot.service('myService', function($rootScope) {
  var myTempService = {
    ToggleSwitchWidgetConfig: [
                { "State": "ON", "Index":1 },
                { "State": "ON", "Index": 2 },
                { "State": "ON", "Index": 3 },
                { "State": "ON", "Index": 4 },
                { "State": "OFF", "Index": 5 },
                { "State": "OFF", "Index": 6 } ],
    SwitchToggled: function($scope) {
    var index = $scope.CurrentSwithIndex;
      var cbId = 'visiblityToggleCB' + index;
      var state = '';
      if ($("#" + cbId).is(':checked'))
        state = 'ON';
      else {
        state = 'OFF';
      }

      this.ToggleSwitchWidgetConfig[+index - 1].State = state;
      var obj = this.ToggleSwitchWidgetConfig;

      var offCount = 0;
      var onCount = 0;
      $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
        if (value.State == 'OFF') {
          offCount++;
        } else if (value.State == 'ON') {
          onCount++;
        }
      });


      if (offCount == obj.length) {
        //If all switches are in OFF, 
        //switch back the current switch to ON state
        this.ToggleSwitchWidgetConfig[+index - 1].State = 'ON';
      }
      if (onCount == obj.length) {
        //If all switches are in ON state,
        //switch bact the current switch to OFF state
        this.ToggleSwitchWidgetConfig[+index - 1].State = 'OFF';
      }
    }
  };
  return myTempService;
});
```

**Directive:**

```
appRoot.directive('toggleSwitchDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "C",
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: "_ToggleSwitchWidget.html"
  }
});
```

The directive will be rendered as:
[image]

Now what I am trying to do, if out of 6 switches if 5 are in **hide** state and if I also try to make the 6th switch to **hide**, it should prevent that,
similar should happen when I try to make all switches to **Show** state.

For this I am changing the $scope variable **ToggleSwitchWidget** (used for populating the switches) accordingly, but the changes in the model not causing the change in the view.
What I am missing or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your js contains errors. Check browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the code reaches this point:

```
witchToggled: function() {
      var cbId = 'visiblityToggleCB' + index;
```

This variable:

```
Index
```

Is not present.

Thus, I:

- put `ng-click="SwitchToggled(config)"` in order to pass the clicked item
- Retrieve it inside the Service: `var index = selected.Index;`

There was another problem, in order to switch OFF/ON the last item, I had to put the `$timeout` in order to force the rendering in the page:

```
(function(input) {

    $timeout(function(){input.State = 'ON'},100);
})(this.ToggleSwitchWidgetConfig[index-1]);
```

Here's the updated working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fcOKiUpXJkZZdnoBpWBK?p=preview

**NOTE**: the timeout is set to 100 mills in order to give the look and feel of something being clicked and then put it to the previous state